# Update table with max value from cartesian product join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables:

| User | Budget | Best_Option |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 100 | Null |
| Mary | 50 | Null |

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Pen | 80 |
| Notebook | 40 |

I need to populate the column "Best_Option" with "Pen" for John, and "Notebook" for Mary as these are the most expensive items they can afford given the budget.

I can find out the maximum by:

```
SELECT  User, max(Price)
    FROM  `tableA`
    join  `tableB`
    WHERE  Budget > Price
    group by  User;
```

How can I get the Item name?

How can I populate Best_Option field with the Item name?

Comment: Sounds like a groupwise-max problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `LIMIT 1` subquery

```
UPDATE tableA
SET Best_Option = (
    SELECT b.Item
    FROM tableB b
    WHERE b.Price <= tableA.Budget
    ORDER BY b.Price DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```